# Converting WAV audio files to MP3 on a server automatically once uploaded?

Tags: python, django, mp3, vps

I'm working on a project, using Python/Django running on a Virtual Private Server, which allows me a blank Linux server box that I can pretty much install whatever I need. The project must allow users to upload an uncompressed WAV file for others to download. These will most probably be served up using Amazon S3. I'm not expecting a massive amount of people to use this site, but obviously scalability is to be thought of.

I'm an intermediate developer, where wrapping my head around using Amazon S3 in Django has been a little bit of a struggle. So I'm looking for a simple and reliable as possible solution to my problem...

Once a user has uploaded an uncompressed WAV file, I would like something to convert this into an MP3 to be used as a preview on the site before another user choices to download it. I'm not really sure how to go about implementing such a feature... Like I say, a simple solution to this would be best for me. Something I can wrap my head around easily! (and to especially implement)

Could anyone offer a solution to this? I would appreciate a good explanation to the process so I can take it in the right direction. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There used to be a module that had bindings for LAME, called `python-lame` but it has died. You can always construct some command line arguments to LAME and invoke it with `os.system`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-doc.html) e.g. something like this may work

```
$ ffmpeg -i audio.wav -acodec mp3 -ab 192k audio.mp3
```

See [docs](http://www.ffmpeg.org) for more details

Comment: This could be the way to go actually... Thank you

Comment: I maintain a small library, [pydub](http://pydub.com) which wraps this functionality :) It's in use in at least one python/django setup that I know of

Answer (score 0):

[gst](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-python.html) can help you with the conversion, once the appropriate codecs are in place.